# Is it better to hide a tableviewcell or filter in data source? (performance issue)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController where I have cells that I want to hide.

What I'm currently doing is hiding the cells with heightForRowAt returning 0 and cellForRowAt returning a cell with isHidden = false. But since I am using this solution, I noticed the app was slower when I'm scrolling in my tableView.

```swift
// Currently returning a height of 0 for hidden cells
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let post = timeline?.postObjects?[indexPath.row], post.hidden ?? false {
        return 0.0
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

// And a cell with cell.isHidden = false (corresponding to identifier "hiddenCell")
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let post = timeline?.postObjects?[indexPath.row] {
        if post.hidden ?? false {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hiddenCell", for: indexPath)
        } else {
            return (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell).with(post: post, timelineController: self, darkMode: isDarkMode())
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about why not apply a filter on the array to totally remove hidden cells of the tableView, but I don't know if filtering them each time is great for performances...

```swift
// Returning only the number of visible cells
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}.count
}

// And creating cells for only visible rows
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let post = timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}[indexPath.row] {
        return (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell).with(post: post, timelineController: self, darkMode: isDarkMode())
    }
}
```

What is the best option? Hiding cells when generating them (first) or exclude them of the list (second)?

Comment: Try both approaches. Test the performance and determine which works better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to let the table view data source methods to deal with a *filtered* version of `timeline`. However, do not do this in `cellForRowAt` method because we need to do it one time but not for each cell drawing.

So, what you could do is to declare `filteredTimeline` and do the filter one time in the `viewDidLoad` method (for instance):

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
    var filteredTimeline // as the same type of `timeline`


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...

        filteredTimeline = timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}

        // ...
    }

    // Returning only the number of visible cells
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredTimeline.count ?? 0
    }

    // And creating cells for only visible rows
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let post = filteredTimeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}[indexPath.row] {
            return (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell).with(post: post, timelineController: self, darkMode: isDarkMode())
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

In case of there is a better place to `filteredTimeline = timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}` rather than `viewDidLoad`, you might need to call `tableView.reloadData()`.

**An alternative you could do:**

if you think that you don't need the original `timeline` you could filter it itself:

```
timeline = timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}
tableView.reloadData()
```

and you will not need an extra filtered array.

---

**Extra tip:**

In case of returning `0.0` value in `heightForRowAt` method for a certain row, `cellForRowAt` will not even get called; For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.row == 0 ?? 0.0 : 100.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // ...
}
```

At this point, `cellForRowAt` should get called only one time because the height for the first row is `0.0`.

Comment: If I create a filtered array, in the memory are objects saved two time (in timeline and filteredTimeline) or the filteredTimeline contains references to timeline (so one object and less memory used)?

Comment: @NathanFallet Well, they would be tow different copies, copy on write won't be applicable if case of using `filter` (more memory), however we should consider the calling of extra `if-statements` each time when aiming to draw a cell...

Comment: @NathanFallet I updated the answer ("An alternative you could do" if it works fro you). Furthermore, Although I would assume that creating an extra filtered array will not eat the memory, you could check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898161/memory-vs-performance

Answer (score 1):

There is no point of having cells with a size of 0. Your best bet is to filter your datasource, but my suggestion would be to keep two arrays at the same time.

But handle the filtering elsewhere then in the numberOfRowsInSection.

```
var filteredObjects = []

func filterObjects() {
    filteredObjects = timeline?.postObjects?.filter{!($0.hidden ?? false)}
}


// Returning only the number of visible cells
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredObjects.count
}

// And creating cells for only visible rows
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let post = filteredObjects[indexPath.row] {
        return (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell).with(post: post, timelineController: self, darkMode: isDarkMode())
    }
}
```

I don't know how you handle the filtering, but whenever you want to apply your filter you simply

```
filterObjects()
tableView.reloadData()
```